# Unable to connect to the remote server when using localhost to sent http request in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, httpclient

I have a basic unit test that checks if a header for an http request is set or not:

```
    public async Task HeaderNotFound()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost");
        // ...set the operation context
        await client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
        // ...assert that the needed header are added
    }
```

The client is set with a custom handler in the test class ctor:

```
client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new SomeHandlerThatAddHeader());
```

The above test used to run with out any issue, but start failing permanently after we updated the build agent pool used in the build pipeline. Running the test result in the following exception:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it 127.0.0.1:80

I could simply switch the uri to a valid one like google.com (since it seems like nothing is starting on localhost) but I would like to keep localhost (I know also that making active connection while unit testing would make it more like an int test). Finally mocking the Httpclient client will override the added `DelegatingHandler`, and it seems like an overkill for such simple test!

How can I fix that please?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of establishing a connection to localhost if nothing is running on localhost, an HTTP server is needed.

You specify that the header is only being added after you use

```
client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
```

So you must perform the HTTP request to a valid server.

Alternatives:

1. As you mentioned, use a valid server address such as google.com (make sure Firewall allows it)
2. Add a server to localhost and connect it (IIS / python -m SimpleHTTPServer / etc)